# Mail Mime image in email body not showing up using MailMime addHtml(...)

Tags: php, html-email, email-attachments, mime-mail

Mail_Mime 1.8.9
Mail 1.2.0
php 5.4.12
project = run from my localhost dev computer (LAN).

Hello, I am attempting to add an image to my email I am sending out using MailMime.  The image never loads. I'll go through the steps below:

Here I am stripping everything off of the image but the image name and extension (ie:noimage.jpg). I then create a link for non image related purposes, I then create the image tag using the stripped image name and extension.

```
$url = substr($baseImage, 36);
$domainName = DomainNameUtil::getWebSiteDomainName();
$projectPath = DomainNameUtil::getPathToProject();
$productUrl = $domainName . $projectPath  . "/client/app/#/products/" . $product->id;
$productLink = "<a href='$productUrl'>$product->name</a>";
$string = "<img src='$url' /><br />";
```

Here I am sending the message

```
$mailConfig = MailConfigurationUtil::getMailConfigurationData();
$headers = array (
  'From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject
);
$crlf = "\n";
$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));
$mime->setHTMLBody($body);
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array (
  'host' => $mailConfig->mailServer,
  'port' => $mailConfig->port,
  'auth' => true,
  'username' => $mailConfig->userName,
  'password' => $mailConfig->password
));

$productManager = new ProductManager();
$ordersManager = new OrdersManager();
$orderVirtualItem =  $ordersManager->getOrderVirtualItemByBoxId($boxId);
$product = $productManager->getProductById($orderVirtualItem->itemId);
$url = $product->baseImage;
$domain = DomainNameUtil::getWebSiteDomainName();
$path = DomainNameUtil::getPathToProject();
$r = substr($url, 5);
$finalUrl = $domain . $path . $r;
$mime->addHTMLImage(file_get_contents($finalUrl),'image/jpeg',basename("noimage"),false, "blackstone");
$body = $mime->get();
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

In the example above, I know the image is called noimage.jpeg, so in the addHtmlImage above I simply stated the name. I am under the impression that the name used in addHtmlImage has to be the same name as the image name in the image src tag in the html body.

When I actually send my email I get the email and I get some text saying there is an image, but the image tag in my email body does not load.
Also, looking at it under firebug it has a proxy attached to the image src. Also it references it as PROXYADDRESS#http://noimage.jpg

[image]

Anyone have experience in this that can help me understand why the image is not loading?

For reference, I saw someone posting this method online and tried copying them.  before this I had even tried putting the whole url in the image src and not adding the image to MIME, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

i got pretty similar problem here.

What i got so far: it depends on phpversion (and installed Mail_Mime). 
Mail_Mime seems to be "broken" under php 5.4.30
If i run my script under php 5.2.17 all images show up correctly
If i run my script under php 5.4.30 all images do not show up correctly

when i compare both sourcecodes, it seems, Mail_Mime under 5.4.30 gets messy with the order of boundarys and the Content-Type:
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; in 5.2.17
Content-Type: multipart/related; in 5.4.30enter image description here

[image: email looks like this]
[image: code comparison]

Answer (score 0):

When specifying a context-id (the last parameter to addHtmlImage()) you must reference the image in the html message correctly: `<img src="cid:context-id@local" />`. Of course replacing context id with your own context id for each image to show.